# Issues installing airflow locally

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I installed airflow locally because i am testing sftp operator in airflow (2.0.0). When I try running this code

```
from airflow.providers.sftp.operators import sftp_operator
from airflow import DAG
import datetime

dag = DAG(
'test_dag',
start_date = datetime.datetime(2020,1,8,0,0,0),
schedule_interval = '@daily'
)

get_operation = SFTPOperator(
            task_id="operation",
            ssh_conn_id="ssh_default",
            local_filepath="route_to_local_file",
            remote_filepath="remote_route_to_copy",
            operation="get",
            dag=dag
            )

get_operation
```

When I run this code python code I am getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_dags.py", line 1, in <module>
    from airflow.providers.sftp.operators import sftp_operator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.sftp'
```

can anyone please tell if I am missing anything in my installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't specify how you installed Airflow I'm assuming you did something like `pip install apache-airflow>=2.0.0`. If you look at the Python dependencies in that environment with `pip freeze` you won't see `apache-airflow-providers-sftp` because as of version 2, Airflow extracts its functionality into provider packages, the vast majority of which need to installed manually, eg: `pip install apache-airflow-providers-sftp`. Now it should work. Supporting documentation https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers/packages-ref.html#apache-airflow-providers-sftp.